# How to change title of a QtQuick 2 window?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qquickview

I am trying to change the default window of my project but it doesn't work.
I am using QtQuick 2.0.
Tried importing QtQuick.Window 2.0 and making Window{} as root object instead of Rectangle{} but it doesn't allow window objects as root.It gives me the following errors:

```
QQuickView only supports loading of root objects that derive from QQuickItem. 

If your example is using QML 2, (such as qmlscene) and the .qml file you 
loaded has 'import QtQuick 1.0' or 'import Qt 4.7', this error will occur. 

To load files with 'import QtQuick 1.0' or 'import Qt 4.7', use the 
QDeclarativeView class in the Qt Quick 1 module.
```

Any ideas on how to change the window title? I'm using Qt 5.1.1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This depends on how you want to use your GUI. If you want to use QML for almost everything, from window creation to the elements in your windows, the following solution may be the best option for you.

### Qt5.1, only for desktop

If you have Qt5.1, you may use the new [ApplicationWindow](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-applicationwindow.html) item from [QtQuick.Controls](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qtquickcontrols-index.html) as you root object in a file named **main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360
    title: "MyWindow"

    Text {
        text: "Hello world!"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

To avoid the error message you get, you need to start your application with a [QQmlApplicationEngine](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtqml/qqmlapplicationengine.html) instead of [QQuickView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qquickview.html). This may be done as follows in your **main.cpp** file:

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);    
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine("main.qml");    
    return app.exec();
}
```

### Qt5.0, (possibly) for environments other than desktop

If using Qt5.1 is not an option for you or you are targeting devices not yet supporting QtQuick.Controls, the alternative is to use [Window](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick-window2-window.html) in the following way. Add this to **main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360
    title: "MyWindow"

    Text {
        text: "Hello world!"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

And let this be your **main.cpp**:

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);    
    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
    component.create();    
    return app.exec();
}
```

This should open a window with the text "Hello World!".

Answer (score 3):

The "Qt Quick Controls - Gallery" sample that ships with Qt 5.1.1 provides a good example. The following code assumes a project structure based on the "Qt Quick 2 APplication (Built-in Types)" template.

In **main.qml**, use:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    title: "Component Gallery"
...
```

In **main.cpp**, use:

```
#include <QtQml>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine("qml/YourProject/main.qml");
    QObject* topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow* window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(topLevel);
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```